# Monte Carlo using pool in python

Tags: python, for-loop, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, montecarlo

how do I change the Monte Carlo section of the code below into a multiprocessing pool with the arrays ARR1 and ARR2 as the outputs of the pool process?

```
import numpy as np

def HS():
    arr1=np.zeros((1,2))
    arr2=np.zeros((1,2))
    arr1 =np.random.random((1,2))
    
    arr2= arr1**4
    return arr1,arr2

length=10000
ARR1 = np.zeros((length,2)) 
ARR2 = np.zeros((length,2)) 

# Monte Carlo   
for i in range(0,10000):
    arr1, arr2 = HS()
    ARR1[i,:]=arr1
    ARR2[i,:]=arr2
```

I have tried several things, but the last I played is below:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

def HS():
    arr1=np.zeros((1,2))
    arr2=np.zeros((1,2))
    arr1 =np.random.random((1,2))
    
    arr2= arr1**4
    return arr1,arr2

length=10000
ARR1 = np.zeros((length,2)) 
ARR2 = np.zeros((length,2))    
# for i in range(0,10000):
#     arr1, arr2 = HS()
#     ARR1[i,:]=arr1
#     ARR2[i,:]=arr2

if __name__=="__main__":
    p=Pool(4)
    arr1, arr2 =p.map(HS,range(length))
    #ARR1[i,:]=arr1
    #ARR2[i,:]=arr2
    p.close()
    p.join
```

Comment: Please show what did you tried. Note that there are plenty of similar questions on stackoverflow already and many tutorial to explain how to use multiprocessing with Numpy starting from the Numpy documentation itself.

Comment: Hi Jerome, I have modified the post to show the last thing I tried. I could not figure out to include the number of iterations of the Monte Carlo.

Comment: `p.join` does nothing. You need not to forget the `()` at the end. AFAIK, `p.close()` should be put after the `join`. In fact, I strongly advise you to use the `with` statement like in the documentation. I think `HS` need a parameter (even though it would not be used). Note that processes will certainly have the same seed and you need to set it (typically by using the missing parameter). Besides this, I strongly advise you not to have anything outside the main that is not in functions when you use multiprocessing (or you might experiment some strange behaviour).